# EXCEL break lines with Web Data

Tags: html, excel, excel-formula

I Trying to import a table (in ASP) from web - to an Excel sheet.

I have a cell in this table with break lines like this:

```
1- RED <br> 
2- BLUE <br> 
3- GREEN <br>
```

When I import this table to excel - I got all break lines in new cells - not in the same cell.

I Try: Replace `<br>` to `CHR10`. doesn't work too

I got: `Red &CHR10& Blue &CHR10& Green &CHR10&`

any idea?

Comment: How are you importing the table?

Comment: hi @zac with Excel - Data > From Web - and informing the URL with HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

REPLACE `<BR>` in HTML code to `<br style='mso-data-placement:same-cell;' />`